# How to make a file writable in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, file-writing

I'm trying to edit pre-added files from Forge MDK https://files.minecraftforge.net/

In eclipse I have no knowledge of java except I can understand some variables and things like that.  If I go to one of the class files it'll say in the bottom right corner "Read-Only"

Nothing appears when I open the file the only thing it does is just open up but wont let me type or backspace.  If anyone could help ill gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Right Click on the File and Select Properties , a new dialog opens up. find for resource where you can see the read /write properties of that file.

Comment: `*.class` files are binary files and can not be edited. Could you name the file (path + file name + extension)?